# What does the code included with new copies of Amalur do?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Included with my copy of Kingdoms of Amalur was a single-use code, like the ones that unlock Catwoman DLC in Batman: Arkham City, and multiplayer mode in several games.  I seem to remember reading somewhere that this code unlocks some extra quests in this game, but I'm not sure exactly what its purpose is.

Does anyone know what all the effects of this code are?  I've already played a bit into the game, would I still benefit from the additional quests (if that information is accurate)?

Comment: Eh... I *think* this is a duplicate of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50011/what-do-i-do-with-kingdom-of-amalurs-steam-key) but that would seem to imply that the accepted answer there is wrong.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, it's possible...  I don't know how DLC for this game is handled on the PC side.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't think it's a duplicate since Steam harasses me about keys I should enter in other games too, not just KoA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a set of starting gear that is based on Mass Effect 3 (Shepard's Battle Armor), and some fancy Chakrams.

It also gives you access to the House of Valor faction quest line, which includes 7 quests. I believe the quests are arena quests which can give you new gear, a new house and some money, but I'm not 100% positive yet since I haven't done it.

You can purchase the code online for 800 MS points/$10 (US), or it is included in the game if you buy it new.